# How to post formcollection correctly in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm currently learning about `mvc` with asp.net. But I got problem when trying to post data from controller.

Here's my code:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {

        PostCareersViewModel career = new PostCareersViewModel
        {
            Title = collection["Title"],
            Description = collection["Description"],
            Photo = collection["Photo"],
            CareerStatus = int.Parse(collection["CareerStatus"]),
            JobDescription = collection["JobDescription"],
            Contact = collection["Contact"],
            MainImage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(collection.Get("Photo"))
        };
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Title", career.Title.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Description", career.Description.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Photo", career.Photo.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CareerStatus", career.CareerStatus.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobDescription", career.JobDescription.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Contact",career.Contact.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("MainImage",career.MainImage.ToString())
        });

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(UrlAddressHelper.Base_Url);

                //var responseTask = client.PostAsync(PostCareerString, new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                //                                  collection.
                //                                      AllKeys.ToDictionary(
                //                                          k => k, v => collection[v])));
                var responseTask = client.PostAsync(PostCareerString, content);
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

for the view, I'm using this code:

```
<section class="ftco-section">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PostCareers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "bg-light p-5 contact-form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <h4>Post New Job Vacancy</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "edit" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Photo, new { type = "file", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CareerStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("CareerStatus", new SelectList(ViewBag.CSListItem, "Value", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CareerStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I got error bad request 400.

It works perfectly if I use this responseTask

```
var responseTask = client.PostAsync(PostCareerString, new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                                                      collection.
                                                         AllKeys.ToDictionary(
                                                            k => k, v => collection[v])));
```

well PostAsJson Async need FormUrlEndcodedContent as parameter and PostAsync need httpcontent as parameret. But it formurlendcoded content works perfectly with PostAsync, And why FormUrlEndcodedContent not running with PostAsJsonAsync?

but I can't convert that `MainImage` Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes cause I wont store it to my `api` as file (Actually I don't know if that method works or not to upload file).

Is there any way to deal with this? Am I doing the correct things like convert `FormCollection` to `model` to `FormUrlEncodedContent` (well it is still give me 400 badrequest) ?

I'm really appreciate every answer that posted. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please shared your view code if possible

Comment: got it sir, the cshtml right?

Comment: Yes please share

Comment: In your job create form images control required?

Comment: when you posting data view to controller data received or not?

Comment: you can got the all data using `model ` class in your action parameter and pass the model in `FormUrlEncodedContent `

Comment: i received the data in that postcareer model. So, if i change the parameter into model i can get the model?

Comment: Please check below answer I'm added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below images Data coming from view.

> Model

[image: Model]

> Also, your images file are comming which is you have select in view

[image: File Control data]

> FormCollection
>   [image: FromCollection Data]

Sample View render for checking[image]

Please find out the code

> Cshtml Page code

```
<section class="ftco-section">
    <div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PostCareers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "bg-light p-5 contact-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <h4>Post New Job Vacancy</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, id = "edit" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Photo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.TextBox("myphoto",null, new { type = "file", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Photo), @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Photo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Photo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CareerStatus, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">                   
                    @Html.DropDownList("CareerStatus", new SelectList(ViewBag.CSListItem, "Value", "Name"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CareerStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobDescription, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDescription, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JobDescription, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contact, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contact, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Contact, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

> Controller code for testing data is coming or not way view to

```
public class PostCareersController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new PostCareersViewModel());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection, PostCareersViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase myphoto)
        {

            PostCareersViewModel career = new PostCareersViewModel
            {
                Title = collection["Title"],
                Description = collection["Description"],
                CareerStatus = int.Parse(collection["CareerStatus"]),
                JobDescription = collection["JobDescription"],
                Contact = collection["Contact"],
            };
            if (myphoto != null)
            {
                string Path = Server.MapPath(string.Concat("~/Upload/", myphoto.FileName));
                myphoto.SaveAs(Path);
                career.Photo = string.Concat(Request.Url.Authority, "/Upload/", myphoto.FileName);
            }
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Title", career.Title.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Description", career.Description.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Photo", career.Photo.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("CareerStatus", career.CareerStatus.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("JobDescription", career.JobDescription.ToString()),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Contact",career.Contact.ToString())
        });

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }

    public class PostCareersViewModel
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Photo { get; set; }
        public int CareerStatus { get; set; }
        public string JobDescription { get; set; }
        public string Contact { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** you need to create one folder or your working application folder name  "**Upload**" when you select file then your file save on folder once it's done then you read and send the JSON request.

Comment: soo, the image that stored in my model just the path?
Need a moment to try this. Thanks sir, ill inform you later

Comment: Ok, please check and let me know if any action required on this :).

Comment: Can i ask something? Why in public ActionResult Create() you put postcareersviewmodel model? Is it alternative way so no need create new PostCareerViewModel?

Comment: No no, it's not like that if you pass the data view to controller not necessary to use `FormCollection` if you use `modelclass` inseted of `FormCollection` then you posting the data it automatic map with respective model `propeties`.

Comment: You have `PostCareersViewModel` model class with respective some properties so please pass out the Action parameter and check that it's mapped automatically.

Comment: Thanks dude, I can post to FormUrlEndcoded now. But the image thing that you show me not work. When I check the param HttpPostedFileBase myphoto, it always null.

Comment: You need to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` in form attribute please check `Html.BeginForm("Create", "PostCareers", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "bg-light p-5 contact-form", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })`

Comment: I did add the enctype, still null. already use the code that you gave but the result sill null. I got the file name posted on my database. but the controller cant get the HttpPostedFileBase.. I wonder why...

Comment: Can we connect remotely after some time?

Comment: Actually I changed my code into this:
`if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
                if (file != null)
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath(string.Concat("~/Upload/", file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    model.Photo = string.Concat(Request.Url.Authority, "/Upload/", file.FileName);
                }
            }`
I just wondering your code cant get the requested file in my IDE. Thanks for offering help to remote. and Lot of thanks :)